# Cannot declare model "Cannot implicitly convert type"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am new to coding with ASP.NET MVC Core and I wanted to create a new model for Checkout books in a library system. 
I created a new sub folder called CheckoutModel and inside it I created `CheckoutModel.cs`
When I run the application it hits me with a bug which tells me:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'LibaryData.Models.Checkout' to
>   'LibaryManagmentSystems.Models.Checkout.CheckoutModel'

I tried to rename a class name and change a subfolder name and model name but again had the same issue.

**CatalogController.cs**

```
using LibaryData;
using LibaryManagmentSystems.Models.Catalog;
using LibaryManagmentSystems.Models.Checkout;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Linq;
using LibaryData.Models;

namespace LibaryManagmentSystems.Controllers
{
    public class CatalogController : Controller
    {
        private ILibaryAsset _assets;
        private ICheckout _checkouts;

        public CatalogController(ILibaryAsset assets, ICheckout checkout)
        {
            _assets = assets;
            _checkouts = checkout;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var assetModels = _assets.GetAll();

            var listingResult = assetModels
                .Select(result => new AssetIndexListingModel
                {
                    Id =result.Id,
                    ImageUrl = result.ImageUrl,
                    AuthorOrDirector = _assets.GetAuthorOrDirector(result.Id),
                    DeweyCallNumber = _assets.GetDeweyIndex(result.Id),
                    Title = result.Title,
                    Type = _assets.GetType(result.Id)
                });
            var model = new AssetIndexModel()
            {
                Assets = listingResult
            };
            return View(model);
        }

        public IActionResult Detail(int id)
        {
            var asset = _assets.GetById(id);
            var currentHolds = _checkouts.GetCurrentHolds(id)
                .Select(a => new AssetHoldModel
                {
                    HoldPlace = _checkouts.GetCurrentHoldPlaced(a.Id).ToString("d"),
                    PatronName = _checkouts.GetCurrentHoldPatronName(a.Id)



                });


            var model = new AssetDetailModel
            {
                AssetID = id,
                Title = asset.Title,
                Type = _assets.GetType(id),
                Year = asset.Year,
                Cost = asset.Cost,
                Status = asset.Status.Name,
                ImageURL = asset.ImageUrl,
                AuthorOrDirector = _assets.GetAuthorOrDirector(id),
                CurrentLocation = _assets.GetCurrentLocation(id)?.Name,
                DeweyCallNumber = _assets.GetDeweyIndex(id),
                CheckoutHistory = _checkouts.GetCheckOutHistory(id),
                ISBN = _assets.GetIsbn(id),
                LatestChechout = _checkouts.GetLatesCheckout(id),
                PatronName = _checkouts.GetCurrentCheckoutPatron(id),
                CurrentHolds = currentHolds

            };
            return View(model);
        }

        public IActionResult Checkout(int id)
        {
            var asset = _assets.GetById(id);

            var model = new Models.Checkout.CheckoutModel
            {
                AssetId = id,
                ImageUrl = asset.ImageUrl,
                Title = asset.Title,
                LibaryCardId ="",
                isCheckOut = _checkouts.IsCheckedOut(id)
            };
            return View(model);
        }

        public IActionResult MarkLost(int assetID)
        {
            _checkouts.MarkLost(assetID);
            return RedirectToAction("Detail", new { id = assetID });
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PlaceCheckout(int assetID, int libaryCardId)
        {
            _checkouts.CheckInItem(assetID, libaryCardId);
            return RedirectToAction("Detail", new { id = assetID });
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PlaceHold(int assetID, int libaryCardId)
        {
            _checkouts.PlaceHold(assetID, libaryCardId);
            return RedirectToAction("Detail", new { id = assetID });
        }

        public IActionResult Hold(int id)
        {
            var asset = _assets.GetById(id);

            var model = new CheckoutModel
            {
                AssetId = id,
                ImageUrl = asset.ImageUrl,
                Title = asset.Title,
                LibaryCardId = "",
                isCheckOut = _checkouts.IsCheckedOut(id),
                HoldCount = _checkouts.GetCurrentHolds(id).Count()
            };
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

**Checkout.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace LibaryData.Models
{
    public class Checkout
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public LibaryAsset LibaryAsset { get; set; }
        public LibaryCard LibaryCard { get; set; }
        public DateTime Since { get; set; }
        public DateTime Until { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**CheckoutModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LibaryManagmentSystems.Models.Checkout
{
    public class CheckoutModel
    {
        public string LibaryCardId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int AssetId { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public int HoldCount { get; set; }
        public bool isCheckOut { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or help?

It displays an error in CatalogController.cs:

```
LatestChechout = _checkouts.GetLatesCheckout(id)

 public Checkout GetLatesCheckout(int assetId)
        {
            return _context.Checkouts
                .Where(c => c.LibaryAsset.Id == assetId)
                .OrderByDescending(c=>c.Since)
                .FirstOrDefault();

        }
```

**AssetsDetailModel.cs**

```
using LibaryData.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using LibaryData.Models;
using System;

namespace LibaryManagmentSystems.Models.Catalog
{
    public class AssetDetailModel
    {

        public int AssetID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string AuthorOrDirector { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string ISBN { get; set; }
        public string DeweyCallNumber { get; set; }
        public string  Status { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
        public string CurrentLocation { get; set; }
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
        public string PatronName { get; set; }
        public Checkout LatestCheckout { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CheckoutHistory> CheckoutHistory { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<AssetHoldModel> CurrentHolds { get; set; }


    }

    public class AssetHoldModel
    {
        public string PatronName { get; set; }
        public string HoldPlace { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually directly provided the relevant code, but it would seem that `_checkouts.GetLatesCheckout(id)` returns one type of object (Checkout), but the `LatestChechout` property is declared as another different type of object (CheckoutModel). You can't just randomly swap one type for another.

Comment: I added method for GetLatesCheckout

Comment: Ok so that returns an object of type `Checkout`, and I'm going to guess that the declaration of `AssetDetailModel.LatestChechout` is `public CheckoutModel LatestChechout`? So like I said, they are two entirely different objects. You can't just expect one to magically morph into the other. How is the code supposed to know how to do that? They are entirely unrelated classes. It's like you told the computer to turn a car into a rabbit or something, without giving any instructions on how to do it. You need to use the same type on both sides of the statement, or write a conversion routine.

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: @Ofiris It's less clear since the latest edit, but the line throwing the error I tihnk is `LatestChechout = _checkouts.GetLatesCheckout(id)`. The previous revision makes that clearer.

Comment: LatestChechout = _checkouts.GetLatesCheckout(id)
In CatalogController.cs
You have the code above

Comment: @nick.name So did you understand my comment above?

Comment: @ADyson sorry, but not so clean :/

Comment: what is confusing you? Can you verify my assertion about the LatestChechout property? I am fairly certain (based on the error message) that I'm correct...

Comment: Yeah, I know that but the fieald LatesCheckout
public  Checkout LatestCheckout { get; set; } is declare in the class, and the class is public
and also  public class Checkout and Checkout GetLatesCheckout(int assetId);
Everything as I see is declare properly

Comment: To give _us_ clarity, show the `AssetDetailModel` class, please, since its the code to populate a property in that object which is causing the error.

Comment: I posted AssetDetailModel.cs

Comment: One notice before:
 public Checkout LatestCheckout { get; set; } hit the error know
It now recognize Checkout data type 
'Checkout' is a namespace but is used like a type LibaryManagmentSystems

Comment: based on that code, the line you reported cannot be giving that error.  The types seem to match now. But I do not really understand your comment above. Are you saying there is now a different problem? It's not clear

Comment: Yes, in AssetDetailModel.cs it not recognize Checkout
public  **Checkout** LatestCheckout { get; set; }
It says Checkout is name but its use as a type

Comment: Probably it is confusing it with the namespace also called Checkout. If possible, avoid giving the same name to namespaces and classes. You can confuse yourself, never mind the compiler

Comment: It now recognize Checkout anywhere.
It regonize as a namespace not as a class

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm saying. If you give your namespace a different name you wouldn't have any confusion

Comment: Thanks @ADyson
Please post this as answer that I can vote up. You help me a lot of :) 
Thank you :)

Comment: No problem, done. You should perhaps consider updating the question to reflect the newer problem, since the code shown in the question now produces that error, and no longer produces the one shown at the top. Otherwise it's a bit confusing for future readers who may have a similar issue.

Comment: Thank you man so much. 
Yes, in the future I will focude on that. 
I just read the rules here, so It will be done :) 
One more time, thank you :) 
YOu have vote up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the second error (in the comments) "data type 'Checkout' is a namespace but is used like a type    LibaryManagmentSystems", the code is confused between the class called `Checkout` and the namespace called `Checkout` which are both accessible from the `AssetDetailModel` (due to the namespace that class is in, and the `using` statements in the file).

To remove this problem you can either

1) Change your class or your namespace so that they no longer have the same name

Or

2) remove the ambiguity in your code by explicitly specifying the full namespace of the checkout class in the property declaration:

```
public LibaryData.Models.Checkout LatestCheckout { get; set; }
```

This will make it clear it is exactly that object which is being referred to (and not the namespace `LibaryManagmentSystems.Models.Checkout`).